# Unable to install pgAdmin4 on CentOS 8

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, pgadmin, centos-8

I am trying to install pgAdmin4 on CentOS 8. It is throwing these errors. I checked python and version 3.6 is already installed.

[image]

Comment: The majority of required packages can be found in `CentOS AppStream x86_64` repository. Is it disabled on your system? What specific command do you run to install pgAdmin4?

Comment: @DanilaVershinin How to check if AppStream is disabled and how to enable it back? To install pgAdmin4, I used: sudo yum install pgAdmin4

Comment: If you're indeed in CentOS (and not RHEL), check that `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-AppStream.repo` exists and has `enabled=1`